# Work around so google doesnt block site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, parsing

Working on a site.

- If I force a site to only allow logged users to access the site how do I parse the pages so google doesn't block the site?

Comment: What do you expect Google to show, and _why_ do you expect Google to show anything if all pages are restricted? You need to have certain public pages so Google can crawl them.

Comment: What Lazar said. Maybe you can make pages that show potential users what they will be seeing when they log in. (minus the good stuff of course)

Comment: Will not google block site because user must login to see what google does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Google Spider to access your site, you need to have some public pages accessible to it.

You can communicate to Google which page to crawl using a site map and [robots.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt) files in your site.

Another technique could be to server different content based type of visitor, if the visitor is a search engine bots, the server return your content, if the visitor is a browser/user you can return only the login page. This technique is not bullet proof as content indexed in the Google Serp is cached and a user can see the cache result any time (you can potentially even do not allow caching for your pages in the serp).

Comment: Will not google block site because user must login to see what google does?

Comment: @MikeMo no, if you are using provide different content based on the client agent, this means, full content for google bots, restricted access for humans.

Comment: @MikeMo If you found my answer useful, please do not forget to upvote it. Thanks!